# Buttons are showing all the elements or nothing when using a foreach loop.Need to set individual targets for buttons

Tags: jquery, laravel

I'm trying to write some code where I have three buttons; 1, 2 and 3. I also have 3 videos that are being retrieved from my database with a `foreach` loop.

On click of button 1 it should display video 1, button 2 should display video 2, button 3 should display video 3 etc.

What would be the jQuery code for this? This is what I've tried:

```html
<script>
  $("#videos").hide();

  $("#button1").on('click', function() {
    $("#videos").toggle();
  });

  $("#button2").on('click', function() {
    $("#videos").toggle();
  });

  $("#button3").on('click', function() {
    $("#videos").toggle();
  });
</script>

<button id="button1">1</button>
<button id="button2">2</button>
<button id="button3">3</button>

<div id="videos">
  @foreach($videos as $video)
    <video width="400" controls>
      <source src="/videos/{{ $video->videofile }}" type="video/mp4">
    </video> 
  @endforeach
</div>
```

When clicking on the buttons all the videos are showing or not showing at all.

How do I set individual targets for the buttons?

Comment: The code will hide/show all the videos on each click. But you have to hide all the videos and show one while clicking the button. Like `$('.videos').hide();` and `$('#video1').show();` while clicking first button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently hiding and showing the `#videos` element which contains all videos when a button is clicked.

You instead need to relate the clicked button to its `video`. You can do this by index to keep the logic DRY.

```js
$('.button').click(function() {
  $('.video').hide().eq($(this).index()).show();
});
```

```css
.video { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="buttons">
  <button class="button">1</button>
  <button class="button">2</button>
  <button class="button">3</button>
</div>

<div id="videos">
  <div class="video">Pretend I'm a &lt;video /&gt; #1</div>
  <div class="video">Pretend I'm a &lt;video /&gt; #2</div>
  <div class="video">Pretend I'm a &lt;video /&gt; #3</div>
</div>
```

The advantage to using this pattern is that you can add an infinite number of videos and it will instantly work without ever needing to touch the JS logic.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are using Laravel > 5.3

try this code

```
<script>
  $("#videos").hide();

  $("#button1").on('click',function(){
     $("#video_1").toggle();
  });

  $("#button2").on('click',function(){
     $("#video_2").toggle();
  });

  $("#button3").on('click',function(){
     $("#video_3").toggle();
  }); 
</script>

 <button id="button1">1</button>
 <button id="button2">2</button>
 <button id="button3">3</button>

<div id="videos">
 @foreach($videos as $video)
 <div id="video_{{$loop->iteration}}" style="display: none;">
  <video width="400" controls>
    <source src="/videos/{{ $video->videofile }}" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>  
 @endforeach
</div>
```

> using style="display:none" to hide all videos initially.
>
> $loop->iteration = the 1-based index of the current item in the loop;